# Primer is to First, as ____ is to Second

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an analog of Primer for "second" in the English language?

If not, here's what I need help with:  I have written a handbook entitled "Primer" that serves as an introductory tutorial.  I am looking for an apt name of a second handbook that serves as a tutorial at an intermediate level, with the "Primer" being a prerequisite.

Comment: The origin of primer is Latin _primus_ so we have to use _secundus_ in some way, I suppose.

Comment: *Primer* isn't derived from *prime*, though it is related; the direct Anglo-Norman borrowing is *primarium*, referring to a book containing excerpts or translations of the [Breviary](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02768b.htm) and other liturgical manuals.

Comment: As a pun, you could use *topcoat* (as in the layer of paint that goes over the primer).

Comment: For cars, the primer is followed by a base coat, followed by a clear coat.

Comment: @jxh That wouldn't make sense to the many of us who don’t pronounce those two words the same way. See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10036 for why this early textbook sense is the one that sounds like it’s ***more prim***, not like the one for paint that sounds like it’s *more prime*.

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks. In that case, I suggest *proper*.

Comment: @jxh in my experience it's _undercoat_ that goes over primer and the top coat goes over the undercoat. Primer is usually pink or white, undercoat provides the majority of the colour and the top coat is pretty much a varnish with some colour in it.

Comment: Primer is to first as gunpowder is to second.

Answer (score 2):

Priming doesn't indicate first other than it may be the first step or steps that should be completed before beginning other tasks.

A second primer would be just that.  A second thing you should do before you start doing the real work, so to speak.  ("Add a second coat of primer." or "You need to read these three handbook primers before taking the course."

To answer your question, it could be titled "Intermediate Handbook: A Second Primer".

> **intermediate** *adjective*
>   1.1 Having or suitable for a level of knowledge or skill between basic and advanced.
>   ‘an intermediate course’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intermediate)

Answer (score -1):

I've come up with a few examples that you may find helpful. (I'm going to assume your handbook is about Cats, because this is the internet.)

- A Cat and Ball Primer

Potential titles for a second book:

- A Cat and Ball Sequel
- Intermediate Cat and Ball Techniques
- Cat and Ball: Next Steps
- Further Cat and Ball Studies
- Cat and Ball 2: Electric Bugaloo